# Karate contains and all key-values did not match error

Tags: api, karate

I try to learn Karate but have some issue and I can't resolve it by myself.

So my Feature is looking rather simple:

```
Feature: Alerting get the list of all alerts
  Background:
    * url 'url'

  Scenario: Retrieve all alerts

    Given path '5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response contains {id: 5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd}
```

The case here is to fetch a response and make sure that given ID is on the list. As far I understand this [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains) keyword contains should lookup only for the given phrase but I get an error: reason: all key-values did not match

This is my console output:

```
allAlertsGet.feature:10 - path: $, actual: {data={name=Baelish of Harrenhal, user=griffin, id=5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd, tags=["Gared"], triggers={prometheus=[{"js_id":"Qarth","labels":["Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone"],"operator":"==","query":"up","value":"1"}]}, trigger_interval=398s, receivers={slack=[{"holdoffTime":"0s","id":"Stalls","message":"Dark and difficult times lie ahead. Soon we must all face the choice between what is right and what is easy.","revokeMessage":"Every flight begins with a fall.","token":"Buckbeak"}]}, hold_cap=4, max_cap=16, factor=2, createDate=1546947669, triggered_date=1546948867, mute_until=0, muted=false, status=3}}, expected: {id=5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd}, reason: all key-values did not match
```

What I have missed? I use karate 0.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the nested structure of your JSON. You can paste this snippet into a `Scenario` and try it, this is a tip - you can experiment quickly without making HTTP requests like this:

```
* def response = { data: { name: 'Baelish of Harrenhal', user: 'griffin', id: '5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd' } }
* match response.data contains { id: '5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd' }
```

EDIT: just to show off a few other ways to do assertions:

```
* match response.data.id == '5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd'
* match response..id contains '5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd'

* def id = { id: '5c348c553a892c000bb1f2dd' }
* match response == { data: '#(^id)' }
* match response contains { data: '#(^id)' }
```

Comment: So as far I understood I missed response.data? So I need to tell Karate that this will be JSON payload not string?

Comment: @Glorifind no, Karate understands JSON by default. I just edited the answer with some other possibilities. I recommend reading the docs and understanding JSON well. and then Json-Path after that