# Karate: verify text contains in a list of kittens in cat return all key-values did not match error

Tags: karate

I have the following code

```
* def cat =
  """
  {
    kittens: [
      {
        id: 23,
        name: 'Bob'
      },
      {
        id: 42,
        name: 'Wild'
      }
    ]
  }
  """
* def id = {id: 23}
```

I am trying to follow [Karate contains and all key-values did not match error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128373/karate-contains-and-all-key-values-did-not-match-error) to resolve all key-values did not match error
here is what I have

```
* match cat == {kittens: '#(^id)'}
* match cat contains {kittens: '#(^id)'}
```

but I get the following error

> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: - path: $, actual: {kittens=[{"id":23,"name":"Bob"},{"id":42,"name":"Wild"}]}, expected: {kittens=#(^id)}, reason: all key-values did not match

Now I have added another colour field for each kitten:

```
* def cat =
  """
  {
    kittens: [
      {
        id: 23,
        colour: 'black',
        name: 'Bob'
      },
      {
        id: 42,
        colour: 'grey',
        name: 'Wild'
      }
    ]
  }
  """
* def id = {id: 23, name: 'Bob'}
```

using the provided answer `cat.kittens contains '#(^id)'` STILL works.

Alternative way to do it is

```
* def id = {id: 23, colour: '#number', name: 'Bob'}
```

Option1 is better as you don't need to specify colour: '#number'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* match cat.kittens contains '#(^id)'
```

For an explanation, read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts

Comment: thanks, Peter, this works great. for each kitten I have added another field colour, sit in-between id and name field. now my id is `{
    id: '23',
    name: 'Bob'
  }` but it is not working. I have to set to `{
    id: '23',
    colour: '#number',
    name: 'Bob'
  }` to get it work. what if I have lots of fields in kitten but I only want to validate 2-3 fields. Is there a way to get around with this issue without specifying `colour: '#number',`?

Comment: @sc30 ask a new question please

Comment: I can only post a new question every 90mins, will post it later on.

Comment: @sc30 yes because it is hard to discuss in comments. from what I understood, my answer itself should work, so I am lost

Comment: Hi, Peter, there is a typo in my code, so your solution actually still works. Again, thanks for the help.